# How do I create a forest of spanning trees in Boost's Graph Library?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm new to Boost's graph library, but it seems quite powerful.  Using other posts I've found, I've managed to create an undirected graph with vertices/edges that have custom classes to hold the other information I need.  I've also managed to create a spanning tree of said graph.  After creating a spanning tree, I do a DFS starting with a source vertex and do my necessary processing in the visitor.  The basic section of my code that achieves this is below:

```
struct InSpanning {
                std::set<EdgeDescriptor> edges;
                bool operator()(EdgeDescriptor e) const { return edges.count(e); }
            } spanning;

            boost::kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(graph, std::inserter(spanning.edges, spanning.edges.end()), boost::weight_map(get(&EdgeInfo::weight, graph)));
            MyVisitor vis();
            boost::filtered_graph<Graph, InSpanning, boost::keep_all> mst(graph, spanning, {});
            boost::depth_first_search(mst, visitor(vis).root_vertex(0));
```

Now, my question, how do I handle the case where my graph is disconnected?  I know I can identify this case via boost::connected_components, but it's not clear to me how to actually alter my code segment above as I'd like to continue to use kruskal's.  Based on documentation, it appears as though my two options are a filtered_graph or subgraph?  Honestly, it seems as though a filtered graph of each connected component would be most reasonable?  My problem is that kruskal's takes a graph as it's first argument, and in my code I use the spanning tree to create the filtered graph in the first place.  So, I'm stuck with a circular problem.  How do I go from a filtered graph or subgraph to a graph object to satisfy the function in order to create a forest of spanning trees?